# Chaining MySQL with subqueries for deletion

Tags: mysql, subquery

We have an ordering system that we're about to launch, however, we need to clear out all the test data for one of the clients. The gateway portion is housing multiple clients due to the way it needed to be setup (ie., the gateway services several different website installations that talk to it).

In doing this, there are many tables I need to ultimately traverse through and remove data for, but orders is where it's tripping me up. We have client_id for most tables, but not all...hence the issue.

Looking to `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE client_id = 1001`. Then, for each of those, we need to `SELECT * FROM order_authorizations WHERE orders.order_id = order_authorizations.order_id`.

**What I'm working with so far:**

```
SELECT * FROM order_authorizations
    WHERE 
        order_id IN (
            SELECT order_id FROM orders
        WHERE 
            order_authorizations.order_id = orders.order_id AND 
            orders.client_id = 1001
    )
;
```

I'm no genius with subqueries, and maybe I'm doing it incorrectly, but I've been through a number of other threads and websites this morning and no matter what, I keep getting a "zero results" returned...so something's not right in my approach. Any ideas?

**Sample Queries w/ Results:**

```
SELECT order_id, client_id FROM `orders` WHERE client_id = 1001 LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 10

order_id    client_id
1237    1001
1236    1001
1235    1001
1234    1001
1233    1001
1232    1001
1231    1001
1230    1001
1229    1001
1228    1001
```

---

```
SELECT order_id
FROM  `order_authorizations` 
WHERE order_id =1237
LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0001 sec )
```

---

The thing is, I can certainly see that there's a value in the order_id column that matches 1237. I see it visually in phpMyAdmin, but the query won't match it apparently with our tests.

**Schema Details:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gateway_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `card_last_four` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_ip_address` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `refunded` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `refund_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1238 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_authorizations` (
  `order_authorization_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tran_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `authorization_code` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `security_key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_authorization_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further convert it into `JOIN`,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    order_authorizations a
        INNER JOIN orders b
            ON a.order_id = b.order_id 
WHERE   b.client_id = 1001
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

Here's the `DELETE` statement,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    order_authorizations a
        INNER JOIN orders b
            ON a.order_id = b.order_id 
WHERE   b.client_id = 1001
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was wondering about JOIN as well. Just ran that query, and somehow still getting zero results returned, though.  :(

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is to convert these SELECT queries into DELETE queries...as we just need to get that data out of the database. I prefer to see the data before screwing with it, though. Full backups taken already  :D

Comment: maybe you have no records at all, can you please add sample records?

Comment: there is no problem converting it. I'll update the answer to convert it into join.

Comment: Yep, no problem. Getting some data now for you. Thanks!

Comment: Just updated the post with some (hopefully) helpful details.  :D

Comment: Also added some schema info. Maybe it's an issue with how it was designed. I didn't create it, it's OpenGateway's system that we license from them, so the software was already built. Just trying to find some awesome master query that will allow me to blow away test data (without hosing the entire database) after testing rounds are done.

Comment: did this query helps or not so i can update it. What is the problem with the query?

Comment: Both your query and mine (the one that says "MySQL returned an empty result set") return zero rows. That's the problem. It's like phpMyAdmin shows that data in the order_authorizations table, but if I try to select and compare order_id on order_authorizations, I get zero rows.

Comment: Might it have something to do with orders having order_id as int() and order_authorizations having order_id as varchar?

Comment: Actually, I don't think the issue is your query. It's probably an issue with our system. The queries are right...tested on another database. BIG thanks to you JW!!  :)